# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() saves with different timezone

Tags: mysql

I am inserting data via MySQL
in local server `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` saves my country time.

Now I'm working in a hosting and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() is 5 hours higher.

I have added

```
SET time_zone = '-5:00'
```

But it doesn't fix the problem

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `UPDATE`.

Try this:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET time_zone = '-5:00'
```

Comment: I need to use this timezone for the whole database

Comment: @Joe I am sorry, but you didn't asked very well... So I it is difficult to undestand what you want to do. Please edit your question and describe your problem a little bit more.